# How to disable zoom in Windows 8 webviews

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm using a webview in an app to display externally hosted content, but the web view lets the user zoom with a pinch gesture and I'd like to disable this.

I can't find any such property on the webview itself, and I've not had any success with a viewport meta tag such as:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/8eecf85d-ebd3-4bc0-ad17-15f342efad25

If the `WebView` works similarly to the WP7 version then you may be able to catch the events in html and cancel them there similarly to [this](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/).

Answer (score 20):

I was able to disable pinch and zoom in Windows 8.1 WebView using following in CSS:

```
html, body
{
  -ms-content-zooming:none;    
}
```

There's a long list stuff try:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771891(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Does this work for windows 8 and with externally hosted content?

Comment: yes, seems to work, anyway, i don't see why it would only work with local content

Comment: Are you modifying the content?  My understand of the question is that the OP can't modify it.

Comment: Working on Windows 10

Comment: This works for disabling pinch zooming on windows 10; but ctrl+scroll wheel zooming still works.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to disable pinch zooming from your C# code, you can use InvokeScriptAsync to inject the -ms-content-zooming:none style as follows:

```
        private void WebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!args.IsSuccess) return;
            DisablePinchZoom(sender);
        }

        private static void DisablePinchZoom(WebView webView)
        {
            string[] args = {"document.body.style['-ms-content-zooming']='none';"};
            webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", args);
        }
```

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/61fa3676-9420-4239-a6d6-b327153884c8/how-do-i-arrange-multiple-webviews-in-a-scrolling-stack-panel?forum=w81prevwCsharp

And if you want to disable the Ctrl + '+/-' or Ctrl + MouseWheel zoom, you can place the Webview inside a ScrollViewer and set ZoomMode="Disabled":

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <WebView NavigationCompleted="WebView_NavigationCompleted" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code, and finally got it to work.

```
html, body
{
  -ms-content-zooming:none;  
  touch-action: none;
  content-zooming: none;
  overflow-y: hidden; // hide vertical
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow-y: none; // hide vertical
overflow-x: none; 
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Just put a

```
<Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
```

over the webview and that is it.

Comment: Er... that'll actually disable ALL interaction with the web view.