# Disable pinch zoom in webbrowser control - win8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, webbrowser-control, pinchzoom

I am writing a Desktop Win8 application using WPF+JavaScript+HTML5

I have the same problem as [How to disable zoom in Windows 8 webviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664818/how-to-disable-zoom-in-windows-8-webviews?rq=1).

As advised there, I tried to disable pinch zoom like: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html

I replaced the `_browser.Descendants<Border>()` with the following

```
RecurseChildren<Border>(_browser).
```

The RecurseChildren function is:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RecurseChildren<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : UIElement
    {
        if (root is T)
        {
            yield return root as T;
        }

        if (root != null)
        {
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);

            for (var idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
            {
                foreach (var child in RecurseChildren<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, idx)))
                {
                    yield return child;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, `var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(_webBrowser);` return 0 - as if there are no childern at all.

Do you know of a way to make it work on Windows 8 desktop appplication?

Thanks

Comment: This question is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875845/wpf-webbrowser-control-disable-pinch-and-zoom-on-win8-desktop.

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to disable pinch zoom in html document (that one in webview)
by css properties:

```
html { -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y; }
```