# WPF WebBrowser Control disable pinch and zoom on win8 desktop

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to disable pinch and zoom on a WPF WebBrowser Control. The enviroment is a win8 Desktop WPF app using .NET4.0. With a regedit setting that tells it to use IE10 engine.

I have already tried using css to disable it but does not work for WebBrowser Control. It does work if the page is viewed from web browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If still interested, you'd need to disable [Disable IE Legacy Input Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacy_input) for WebBrowser control. I've just answered similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170011/c-sharp-webbrowser-panningmode/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239941/wpf-xaml-on-windows-8-in-desktop-mode-webbrowser-prevent-pinch-zoom/), with a working [sample project](http://goo.gl/mrgBon).