# WPF/XAML on Windows 8 in Desktop mode, webbrowser, prevent Pinch/Zoom

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF desktop project running an webbrowser control on an Asus tablet running Windows 8.  To my understanding the webbrowser control uses the system's browser version and renders the page, which means IE10.
I am trying to prevent pinch zoom on the browser because our users keep messing up the pages for our next customer.
I have tried using the 
     `-ms-content-zooming:none;-ms-touch-action: none;` on the html,body,div,img,ul,li elements on the page trying to target each element to prevent our image and elements from zooming in the browser's window.

Is there a way to prevent the pinch/zoom functionality at all.  I also have the viewport tag set to user-scalable none.  Am I missing something?  Is there a way to get around this?  Is this happening in the control itself or in the browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to disable [IE Legacy Input Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacy_input) for WebBrowser control. I've just answered a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170011/c-sharp-webbrowser-panningmode/), you could find a code sample [here](http://goo.gl/mrgBon).