# How can I disable zooming in the WebBrowser .NET control

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I have a forms project that is using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

This application is being used on a touch screen windows 8.1 machine. I want to disable the zoom function so people can't pinch zoom. The normal meta tag tricks that would work on a mobile device are not working so I would like to just disable zoom in this control.

Comment: I think this is using using Microsoft.Phone.Controls, not  System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Comment: My comment was to someone who posted a Windows phone 7 solution, they have since deleted their comment.

Comment: Then perhaps you should delete yours too.. but then I'll have to delete mine.. and oh its a vicious cycle! :)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17875845/1768303), it should enable the meta tag or CSS tricks.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without a global registry change?

Comment: Not that I know. Although it's not "global" as it uses the HKCU hive which doesn't require admin rights (unlike HKLM).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [blog post](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html).

The author was writing in the context of WP7 but the idea should still apply. If you can break down the flow of calls and events, you should be able to intercept the zoom events and cancel them before they are actually applied.

Comment: I will try this concept, but this is a completely different control and the examples are not directly useful.