# Windows 8.1 store app WebView zoom issues - Caliburn Micro involved

Tags: webview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, caliburn.micro

I've been trying now for the better part of a day to figure out something that is surely very simple - **zooming in a WebView using the pinch gesture** in a Caliburn Micro application.

I have a Caliburn Micro app that has several pages, one of which has a `WebView` on it.  I've been trying to get that `WebView` to zoom without putting it in a separate `ScrollViewer` b/c the `ScrollViewer` seems to introduce other behavior oddities.  I'm not having any luck getting the `WebView` to zoom.

**EDIT:**  I'm basing my "it don't work" claim on behavior I'm experiencing when I'm remote debugging on a local Dell Venue tablet.

Here is what my ShellView page looks like in the big Caliburn Micro app (with the non-working `WebView`):

```
<Page
    x:Class="FooBar.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <WebView x:Name="WebView"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Despite my best efforts, this doesn't allow me to zoom.

To try to see what I'm doing wrong, I created another project that's a very simple, one-page Caliburn Micro app, with the **exact same markup** as the multi-page CM app and it works as expected.  More specifically, the app starts, creates the first view - ShellView - loads the `WebView` source and then proceeds to allow me to zoom without issues.

I've added all the styles from the non-working app to the working app, thinking maybe there's something going on there I'm not aware of and the second app still works.

I've tried explicitly setting the `Height/Width` of the `WebView` and the containing `Grid` of the non-working app without any luck.  I'm not setting any `Height`s/`Width`s of any object in the working app.

I know I've got to be doing something/omitting something very silly, but I can't see it.  Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was the website itself I was navigating to.  It had the `-ms-content-zooming` CSS attribute set to `none`.

I found that CSS attribute from this SO question:  [How to disable zoom in Windows 8 webviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664818/how-to-disable-zoom-in-windows-8-webviews).

Then I used this SO post to inject it into my WebView:  [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript).

Worked like a charm and I was able to immediately start zooming.  Thanks, SO!!!